# How to download a file with a script Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, vba, ssis, script-task

I am struggling to use below vba in SSIS script Task. Basically it downloads a file from web and saves it on a shared drive . File is then loaded in SQL server.I have tried the code and it works in Excel VBA.I have modified the URL for security purposes. Below is just an example

```
`Const MYURL = "https://123.123.co.uk&filename=Test.xls"

 Sub DataScraping()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
objHTTP.Open "GET", MYURL, False
objHTTP.SetCredentials "1234", "1234", HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER

objHTTP.Send

Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Write objHTTP.ResponseBody
oStream.SaveToFile ("\\C\files\Test\file13 " & Format(Now(), "ddMMyyyy 
HHmmss") & ".xls")
oStream.Close
End Sub'
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to use above vba in SSIS script task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a script task using C#:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("1234","1234"); // user,pword
wc.DownloadFile("https://123.123.co.uk?filename=Test.xls"
                ,@"c:\Test"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".xls");
```

Comment: Hi @KeithL Many thanks for your reply. Rest of the code looks great, however getting an error message on wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredentials

Comment: Type or namespace name NetworkCredentials doesnot exist in namespace system.Net(or Are you missing an assembly referance?)

Comment: In solution explorer usually on right side. ricght click reference and "Add Reference" and add System.Net

Comment: Hi Keith, Did that, now error lines have gone. But still when i tried to close the script task after saving the code, it pops up with error message that compiled script has errors in it. I can't execute script error task.

Comment: This is the actual error Keith 'NetworkCredentials' does not implement interface member 'ICredentials.GetCredential(Uri, string)'

Comment: Many thanks Keith. Took me good few hours but managed to find the issue.Rest of the code is correct, however new System.Net.NetworkCredentials is without "s" at the end. Many thanks for your help. Top man.

Comment: Sorry. I had to type it out without visual studio. Glad you got your answer